# Is this a correct analysis of an adverbial prepositional phrase?

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, noun-clause

I am trying to analyse what I judge a compound sentence with an adverbial phrase (in *italics*) placed at the beginning:

> *In what turned out to be a common experience for many people who tried to create Internet businesses*, they had a successful website, but they didn't really make any money from it.

My answer is that it modifies one of the verbs (either *had* or *make*, or maybe both) that come right after in the independent clauses. I am also guessing that it complements the first, *had*.

Here's why:

- “*what turned out to be a common experience for many people who tried to create Internet businesses*” is a noun clause:

  - it is introduce by an “-wh” word (*what*), and it is grammatically a noun; therefore, this entire segment functions as the object of the preposition *In*;
  - Supplements to the analysis:

    - “*to be a common experience for many people who tried to create Internet businesses*” is an infinitive phrase (noun), the object of the phrasal verb *turned out*.

      - “*a common experience*” is a noun and “*for many people who tried to create Internet businesses*” is an adjective prepositional phrase.

        - “*who tried to create Internet businesses*” is a relative (adjective) clause modifying the noun *people* along with the adjective *many*.

Is the evaluation correct?

Comment: No: The PP is a supplementary adjunct, and hence it doesn't modify anything. Note also that the expression "what turned out to be a common experience for many people who tried to create Internet businesses" is not a clause but a **noun phrase** in a 'fused' relative construction.

Comment: Thanks again, @BillJ. May I infer that what wasn't mentioned is correct?

Comment: @BillJ. I agree on the PP being an adjunct because its removal doesn't influence the actual meaning of the sentence. However, isn't what follows its preposition really a clause because of the phrasal verb turned out?

Comment: I mean, “what” seems to be acting as noun + relative pronoun together, meaning ‘the thing(s) which’, and starting a clause that is the object of the preposition “In”. So we have a subject (what) and a phrasal verb (turned out), hence a clause.

Comment: You are on the right lines. It's an NP in what is known as a **fused** relative construction, just as it would be an NP in the non-fused equivalent "the thing [which turned out to be a common experience for many people who tried to create Internet businesses]", where the bracketed relative clause is modifying "thing". Thus, the single word "what" combines, or fuses, the two functions of antecedent and relative pronoun.

Comment: Now it's clearer. Would you have a reference on the topic of fused relative constructions?

Comment: [link](docdroid.net/t/15kj/fused-relatives-pdf)

Comment: Try: docdroid.net./t5k/fused-relatives-pdf

Comment: "Not found." Is the upload limited by time?